# When inheriting a class can you generate all the override functions and methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I'm adding a new class which inherits from the the RoleProvider, I then need to add all the differant override functions. Is there a quick way to generate them via the IDE?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move cursor to your class declaration. If you have ReSharper installed, press *Alt* + *Enter*. If not, press *Ctrl* + *.* (dot). You'll see what to do next. For instance *Ctrl* + *.* will prompt you with "Implement abstract class RoleProvider".